# Traceless-transverse gauge vs traceless-transverse part?

Tags: general-relativity, gauge-theory

In Hobson et al (2006) pg514 they write the formula for the flux in the traceless-transverse *gauge*:
$$\newcommand{\p}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}} \newcommand{\f}[2]{\frac{ #1}{ #2}} \newcommand{\l}[0]{\left(} \newcommand{\r}[0]{\right)} \newcommand{\mean}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}\newcommand{\e}[0]{\varepsilon} \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>} F(\vec n)=-\f{c^4}{32 \pi G} \left<(\partial_t h_{ij}^{TT})(\vec n \cdot \vec \nabla) h_{TT}^{ij}\right>$$
They then take the quadrupole formula:
$$\bar h^{ij}=-\f{2G}{c^6 r}\ddot I^{ij}$$
and take the traceless-transverse *part* which from what I can tell means they do the following:
$$\bar h^{ij}-\f{1}{3} \delta^{ij} \bar h=-\f{2G}{c^6 r}(\ddot I^{ij}-\f{1}{3}\delta_{ij} \ddot I)$$
$$\equiv -\f{2G}{c^6 r}\ddot J^{ij}$$
They then project this onto 'a spatial surface orthogonal to the radial direction at any point' using the operator:
$$P_i^k P_j^l-\f{1}{2}P_{ij}P^{kl}$$
to get:
$$(P_i^k P_j^l-\f{1}{2}P_{ij}P^{kl})(\bar h^{ij}-\f{1}{3} \delta^{ij} \bar h)=-\f{2G}{c^6 r}\ddot J^{ij}_{TT}$$
They then call (implicitly) the left hand side of this $h_{TT}^{ij}$ and start treating it as the metric tensor in the traceless-transverse gauge. Please can someone explain to me why this is valid? Since to me
$$(P_i^k P_j^l-\f{1}{2}P_{ij}P^{kl})(\bar h^{ij}-\f{1}{3} \delta^{ij} \bar h)$$
is simply the traceless-transverse PART of $h_{ij}$ used in the gauge used in the quadrapole formula rather then $h_{ij}$ in the traceless-transverse gauge (i.e. $h_{ij}^{TT}$).

**Edit**

Just to make what I am asking clearly; If we have $\bar h_{kl}$ in an arbitrary gauge  can we always retrieve the TT-gauge by using 
$$\bar h_{ij}^{TT}=(P_i^k P_j^l-\f{1}{2}P_{ij}P^{kl})\bar h_{kl}$$
and does it matter what unit vector $n_i$ we use in the projection operator?

Comment: Yes, this is a dirty canonical trick used already in some of the old papers on this topic. Maybe I will recall what was the resolution for me when I was also annoyed by this when first studying it.